# tkinter: cleanly destroy auto-wrapping widgets created in tk.Text with window_create

Tags: python, tkinter

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846761/13525512) answer, I successfully created my own widget where labels are wrapped automatically in a `Text` element using `window_create`.

I'm also able to destroy these labels using `nametowidget`. However, the `window` element of the deleted widgets remains and is returned by `dump`.

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn_frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
btn_frame1.pack(side='top', fill='x')
create_labels_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame1, text='Create Labels')
create_labels_btn.pack(side='left')
delete_labels_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame1, text='Delete Labels')
delete_labels_btn.pack(side='right')

label_text_field = tk.Text(root, height=7, width=40)
label_text_field.pack(side='top')

dump_text_field_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Dump text field')
dump_text_field_btn.pack(side='top')

dumping_text = tk.Text(root, height=7, width=40)
dumping_text.pack(side='top')

def create_labels():
    for i in range(1, 7):
        lbl = tk.Label(label_text_field, width=12, text=f'label {i}')
        label_text_field.window_create("insert", window=lbl, padx=8, pady=8)

create_labels_btn['command'] = create_labels

def delete_labels():
    for lbl in label_text_field.dump("1.0", "end"):
        if lbl[0] =='window' and lbl[1]:
            label_text_field.nametowidget(lbl[1]).destroy()

delete_labels_btn['command'] = delete_labels

def dump_text_field():
    dumping_text.delete("1.0", "end")
    for obj in label_text_field.dump("1.0", "end"):
        dumping_text.insert('end', str(obj) + '\n')

dump_text_field_btn['command'] = dump_text_field

root.mainloop()
```

After creating and deleting my labels. The deleted elements are still visible in the `dump` output (the widget was succesfully deleted though and the remaining name is only an empty string):

[image]

How can I cleanly remove the associated `window` so that they don't add up over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the items from the `Text` widget using the index returned by `.dump()`.  But you need to remove them in reverse order, otherwise the *index* will be wrong after removing the first item.

```py
def delete_labels():
    for lbl in label_text_field.dump("1.0", "end")[::-1]:  # get the items in reverse order
        if lbl[0] =='window' and lbl[1]:
            label_text_field.nametowidget(lbl[1]).destroy()
            label_text_field.delete(lbl[2]) # remove item from text box as well
```

Actually you can pass `window=1` to `dump()` to return *window* items only:

```py
def delete_labels():
    for lbl in label_text_field.dump("1.0", "end", window=1)[::-1]:
        if lbl[1]:
            label_text_field.nametowidget(lbl[1]).destroy()
            label_text_field.delete(lbl[2])
```

Comment: @Tranbi: you should use `destroy` unless you re-use the labels later. Otherwise you end up with a memory leak.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks for the heads-up @BryanOakley! In my real code, I destroy it first anyway... But it's good to know!

Comment: @BryanOakley btw I might have upvoted/benefited from half a dozen of your tkinter answers for the project I'm working on... Thanks for your valuable contributions!